# How to pass the original value and not the replace number ( * )

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I mask the numbers of SSN obviously for security... but when I submit, the variable fill with "***-**-****" and is suppose to grab the original input ex. 123-45-6789. I just want to mask that input.

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
        $('#ssn').keyup(function () {
            var val = this.value.replace(/[^\d\*]/g, '').replace(/\d/g, '*');
            var newVal = '';
            var sizes = [3, 2, 4];
            var maxSize = 10;

            for (var i in sizes) {
                if (val.length > sizes[i]) {
                    newVal += val.substr(0, sizes[i]) + '-';
                    val = val.substr(sizes[i]);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            newVal += val;
            this.value = newVal;
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SolicitantDataView.SSN, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-12 col-md-3 required" })

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SolicitantDataView.SSN, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ssn ssnControl", @id = "ssn", @maxlength = "11" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SolicitantDataView.SSN, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
```

I try this way but the require method not work anymore...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.ssn').unmask().maskSSN('999-99-9999', { maskedChar: 'X', maskedCharsLength: 5 });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

By `replace()` ing the val, you override the original typed data. That's why you get only asterisks. A simple aproach would be using a `hidden` control input, in which you store the typed value before masking. But the right thing to do is to use a js mask extension which supports SSN (or, even better, a custom mask).

Comment: can you explain with a example, I'm new at js =/

Comment: I do it like this way  $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.ssn').unmask().maskSSN('999-99-9999', { maskedChar: 'X', maskedCharsLength: 5 });
        }); but the require gone... why?